# Crystal Reports cannot find file

Tags: crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

I get the following error on the build of a new application that uses Crystal Reports for VS 2010. On my desktop the reports run, moving to the server has resulted in the following.

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I developed the reports on a 32 bit os and moved to 64 bit server. The runtime download and install was ver 13_0_4.

Are there references that I am missing or do I need to reinstall the runtime? Do I need to install the Merge Module also?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: If you need to show report for 64 bit server, then specific assembly needs to be there. You need to install latest patch.